# Fastest way to get pairs of range(n)?

Tags: python, performance, combinations

Imagine you want to process all pairs of the numbers 0 to n-1, for example for `n = 4` that's these six pairs:

```
[(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3)]
```

Three ways to create those pairs:

```
list(combinations(range(n), 2))

[(i, j) for i, j in combinations(range(n), 2)]

[(i, j) for i in range(n) for j in range(i+1, n)]
```

Benchmark results for `n = 1000`:

```
44.1 ms ± 0.2 ms  f_combinations_pure
57.7 ms ± 0.3 ms  f_combinations
66.6 ms ± 0.1 ms  f_ranges
```

Note I'm not really interested in just *storing* the pairs `(i, j)`. That's just a minimal example usage of `i` and `j` so that we can compare different approaches without much overhead. In reality, you want to *do* something with `i` and `j`, for example `[my_string[i:j] for ...]` to get substrings (the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73292710/12671057) where [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73292710/which-is-the-most-efficient-method-for-finding-all-subsequent-substrings-of-a-gi?noredirect=1#comment129439969_73292755) inspired this). So the `list(combinations(...))` one doesn't really count here, and I show it just to make that clear (although I still liked seeing how fast it is).

Question 1: Why is `f_ranges` slower than `f_combinations`? Its `for i in` runs only `n` times overall, so it's insignificant compared to the `for j in`, which runs `n*(n-1)/2` times. And `for j in range(...)` only assigns one number, whereas `for i, j in combinations(...)` builds and assigns *pairs* of numbers, so the latter should be *slower*. Why is it *faster*?

Question 2: What's the fastest way you can come up with? For fair comparison, it shall be a list comprehension `[(i, j) for ...]` producing the same list of pairs.

(As I'm including an answer myself (which [is encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)), I'm including benchmark code there.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### About question 1: Why is `range` slower than `combinations`?

While `for j in range(...)` indeed has the advantage of assigning just one number, it has the *disadvantage* of creating them over and over again. In Python, numbers are objects, and their creation (and deletion) takes a little time.

`combinations(...)` on the other hand first creates and stores the number objects only once, and then reuses them over and over again in the pairs. You might think *"Hold on, it can reuse the **numbers**, but it produces the pairs as `tuple` objects, so it **also** creates one object per iteration!"*. Well... it has an optimization. It actually reuses the same `tuple` object over and over again, filling it with different numbers. *"What? No way! Tuples are immutable!"* Well... ostensibly they're immutable, yes. But if the `combinations` iterator sees that there are no other references to its result tuple, then it "cheats" and modifies it anyway. At the C code level, it can do that. And if nothing else has a reference to it, then there's no harm. Note that `for i, j in ...` unpacks the tuple and doesn't keep a reference to it. If you instead use `for pair in ...`, then `pair` is a reference to it and the optimization isn't applied and indeed a new `result` tuple gets created every time. See the source code of [combinations_next](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/141f2517fc36cc7a0caf177f270edb6d39cf3d23/Modules/itertoolsmodule.c#L2673) if you're interested.

#### About question 2: What's the fastest way?

I found four faster ways:

```
44.1 ms ± 0.2 ms  f_combinations_pure
51.7 ms ± 0.1 ms  f_list
52.7 ms ± 0.2 ms  f_tee
53.6 ms ± 0.1 ms  f_copy_iterator
54.6 ms ± 0.1 ms  f_tuples
57.7 ms ± 0.3 ms  f_combinations
66.6 ms ± 0.1 ms  f_ranges
```

All four faster ways avoid what made the `range` solution slow: Instead of creating (and deleting) Θ(n²) `int` objects, they reuse the same ones over and over again.

`f_tuples` puts them into a tuple and iterates over slices:

```
def f_tuples(n):
    nums = tuple(range(n))
    return [(i, j)
            for i in nums
            for j in nums[i+1:]]
```

`f_list` puts them into a list and then before each `j`-loop, it removes the first number:

```
def f_list(n):
    js = list(range(n))
    return [(i, j)
            for i in range(n)
            if [js.pop(0)]
            for j in js]
```

`f_copy_iterator` puts them into a tuple, then uses an iterator for `i` and a [*copy*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html#copy.copy) of that iterator for `j` (which is an iterator starting one position after `i`):

```
def f_copy_iterator(n):
    nums = iter(tuple(range(n)))
    return [(i, j)
            for i in nums
            for j in copy(nums)]
```

`f_tee` uses [itertools.tee](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.tee) for a similar effect as `copy`. Its `JS` is the main iterator of `j` values, and before each `j`-loop, it discards the first value and then tees `JS` to get a second iterator of the remaining values:

```
def f_tee(n):
    return [(i, j)
            for JS in [iter(range(n))]
            for i in range(n)
            for _, (JS, js) in [(next(JS), tee(JS))]
            for j in js]
```

#### Bonus question: Is it worth it to optimize like those faster ways?

Meh, probably not. Probably you'd best just use `for i, j in combinations(...)`. The faster ways aren't much faster, and they're somewhat more complicated. Plus, in reality, you'll actually do something with `i` and `j` (like getting substrings), so the relatively small speed advantage becomes even relatively smaller.

But I hope you at least found this interesting and perhaps learned something new that *is* useful some day.

#### Full benchmark code

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lVJBbtswELzrFQv0EKpVDTtpgMKAT73lVDS9CYKgWsuErkQRJFXEMPKofqEfc7mkKCm2E7Q6UcPh7M7sqr197OTNZ6WPxxo58HLbtT@ErKzopClVr5HJdJ2A@zTaXktohLFszmK6kg9Ey@A6TZMkORc61ciZyGCXAu800AmEhFcli1HSo2@LkVJ87JHdhIgPqwzkTM/2qpnpyb41sAGPjh2kb5byT8Yy9Je7KutiquHjihV2pO@Rf5MfnQgO@c4sVKfYMi2mijtTzAJX@1JY1JXt9KkpwtmJs/@xRuKMoHl8iK/MwkPxI427exLJfRdj/eKM9sL02W2ZAbu7d/om9WpM4pN1iNsSasUdLkjOYuIURO4ZF/Y8u3ARsbB48S@sTfyjcU5vZyMY6YiJK89114IVLQoLolWdtuBirPrGloRqqIy/DkQSsV3XmMh90Rb5DTxjHWSs2I7EFiuZObzGX4Himq9JMVybx57zZnhN/U4F1D5J3sGXTmvcWonGJPik3NGlxk2@LNhquVymCaXKKVVu4uyNc0GsgUFgZYxzMN5tIGhRha8aVaXRj8c5FvIhIeM0nQNfQx72eyjx7JeNbBrGh2WzfpAW3sMKb4IMkY2zgTXzWjkv0nx9WxTz7eRXB0qHWZOuPy1W/Bnciv/5DQeflodvInxFnX4P3Z2s5vXt0MeQJeMmeD5LxpNspSkcaotNS30xNPpQ1ufs6GlRKeUIjEgfg/REqrEZZKn3b/5kpnEN8XC3Pj9xv/GRDkaUFtKyGHIGfFGWsmqxLNPj8S8)

```
def f_combinations_pure(n):
    return list(combinations(range(n), 2))


def f_combinations(n):
    return [(i, j) for i, j in combinations(range(n), 2)]


def f_ranges(n):
    return [(i, j) for i in range(n) for j in range(i+1, n)]


def f_tuples(n):
    nums = tuple(range(n))
    return [(i, j) for i in nums for j in nums[i+1:]]


def f_list(n):
    js = list(range(n))
    return [(i, j) for i in range(n) if [js.pop(0)] for j in js]


def f_copy_iterator(n):
    nums = iter(tuple(range(n)))
    return [(i, j) for i in nums for j in copy(nums)]


def f_tee(n):
    return [(i, j)
            for JS in [iter(range(n))]
            for i in range(n)
            for _, (JS, js) in [(next(JS), tee(JS))]
            for j in js]


fs = [
    f_combinations_pure,
    f_combinations,
    f_ranges,
    f_tuples,
    f_list,
    f_copy_iterator,
    f_tee
]

from timeit import default_timer as time
from itertools import combinations, tee
from statistics import mean, stdev
from random import shuffle
from copy import copy

# Correctness
expect = fs[0](1000)
for f in fs:
    result = f(1000)
    assert result == expect

# Prepare for timing
times = {f: [] for f in fs}
def stats(f):
    ts = [t * 1e3 for t in sorted(times[f])[:5]]
    return f'{mean(ts):4.1f} ms ± {stdev(ts):3.1f} ms '

# Timing
for i in range(25):
    shuffle(fs)
    for f in fs:
        start = time()
        result = f(1000)
        end = time()
        times[f].append(end - start)
        del result

# Results
for f in sorted(fs, key=stats):
    print(stats(f), f.__name__)
```

Comment: Your "Bonus Question" is an important point.  Digging into micro-optimizations like this, before you even know whether the generation of these tuples is a bottleneck, is the classic disease "premature optimization", and has been the cause of many bazillions of wasted programmer hours.

Comment: @TimRoberts Yeah, most of the time when I do micro-optimize, it's for fun and out of curiosity, and to gain better understanding of things. This case, as mentioned, was inspired by comments, particularly the claim that `for i, j in combinations` is faster than the nested range loops because it is compiled code. Which isn't the reason, as it doesn't compete with the nested range loops but just with the inner one. So I'm hoping to at least correct that misconception :-). And sometimes I micro-optimize not because something is too slow, but for speed competitions. Finally, without trying ...

Comment: ... micro-optimizations, I wouldn't know how much or little impact they have. If I try one and find out it's negligible, then I know that for the future. But I need to try it first.

Comment: Fascinating stuff - I especially liked the question 2 parts. Thanks for taking the time to research and write it up.